# Active relation order not ordering correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have records I need to order with a date attribute. In my code I call:

```
records.order("`records`.date esc")
```

however this doesn't seem to work.

If I run:

```
records.order("`financial_transactions`.date asc").pluck(:date)
```

I get:

```
[Fri, 09 Dec 2016, Wed, 07 Dec 2016, Sun, 25 Jun 2017, Sat, 25 Mar 2017]
```

which is obviously incorrect. I also get the same result if I run:

```
 records.order("`records`.date desc").pluck(:date)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Rails 4+, this should work for descending order:

```
records.order(date: :desc).pluck(:date)
```

And if you want them in ascending order, you can just do:

```
records.order(:date).pluck(:date)
```

For Rails 3.2:

```
records.order('records.date desc').pluck(:date)
records.order('records.date asc').pluck(:date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Rails 5, try

records.order(date: :desc).pluck(:date)

If you want them ascending, do this:

records.order(date: :asc).pluck(:date)

Comment: This answer is a nearly exact duplicate of my answer below.